# How to check if two JNI Arrays point to the same memory location?

Tags: android-ndk

I have two arrays:

```
auto inputArray = reinterpret_cast<jbyteArray>(mainEnv->NewGlobalRef(imageDataArray));
auto output = reinterpret_cast<jfloatArray>(mainEnv->NewGlobalRef(data));
```

When I try:

```
auto input = env->GetByteArrayElements(inputArray, nullptr);
```

I'm getting this error:

"JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: attempt to get byte primitive array elements with an object of type float[]"

My guess is "inputArray" (byte array) point to the same memory location of "output" (float array).

How can I check that?

Comment: Casting the `jobject` makes little sense as it won't change the type of the underlying Java object. If you really need to access the data as something other than its actual type you should perform the cast after you've obtained the native pointer.

Comment: These are the real types in Java. I'm casting them because I want to operate with them at the native environment. So "inputArray" is a byte array in both environments. I've checked it so many times that I can't count anymore. :(

Comment: Well, I suggest that you write up a complete minimal code example that can be used to reproduce this issue. If that example doesn't end up having the same problem then you need to determine in what way it differs from your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell if two object references point to the same object with the JNI `IsSameObject` function.

The error message is telling you that you're calling `GetByteArrayElements` on a `float[]`.  Getting the array object's class (with `GetObjectClass`) would let you query the class of the object at the point it's passed to native code, so you can confirm that the arrays have the types you expect.  From there you can narrow your focus and figure out where things are going wrong.